# Stripe fetch customer by customerID is returning empty

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, stripe-payments

I am trying to fetch all invoices of a customer using Stripe API PHP, but I am getting empty, although I have made several transactions, but I still cannot get all the invoices listed.

This is how I am trying to fetch all the invoices:

```
print_r(\Stripe\Invoice::all(["customer" => $customer_id]));
```

Comment: try it : print_r(\Stripe\Invoice::where('customer',$customer_id)->get());

Comment: @Alihosseinshahabi: Call to undefined method Stripe\Invoice::where()

Comment: Is `Invoice‍` a `Model`?
Please put it

Comment: If you get nothing it means that this customer has no Invoice. They might have Charges and you mixed both resources? Just look at the customer in the dashboard to confirm!

Comment: @koopajah: i guess you are right, so how to generate invoices for charges?

Comment: You don't get an invoice for a charge in that case. That is not something Stripe supports. You likely meant an email receipt: https://stripe.com/docs/receipts

Answer (score -1):

this was asked a while ago, though you can now create one-off invoices for charges to your customers. This will send them a hosted invoice page where they can pay the invoice via card or ACH (depending on your settings and country support)

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/sending#sending-one-time-invoices

This answer is regarding the most recent question on how to create invoices for charges to the customer